# How do I get forex rates historically from a range of dates in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, currency, forex

Im able to get the rates in real time and of a particular time in the year. But how can I just ask for a range of dates and the currency value for that day through

```
 from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
    ...: import datetime
    ...: 
    ...: c = CurrencyRates()
    ...: 
    ...: dt = datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 27, 11, 21, 13, 114505)
    ...: 
    ...: print(c.get_rate('CAD', 'USD', dt))
0.7072353585464853
```

My objective is to have a table that has

```
Rate   DateTime                Currency
0.702   08-01-2007 1:15pm      CAD - USD
0.712   08-01-2007 1:16pm      CAD - USD
```

and so on.Keep an interval by minute. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -

```
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
c = CurrencyRates()

df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], format='%d-%m-%Y %I:%M%p')
df['Rate_'] = df.apply(lambda x: c.get_rate(x['Currency'].split('-')[0].strip(), x['Currency'].split('-')[1].strip(), x['DateTime']), axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
                Rate            DateTime   Currency              Rate_
0 0.7020000000000001 2007-01-08 13:15:00  CAD - USD 0.8510666143174977
1 0.7120000000000001 2007-01-08 13:16:00  CAD - USD 0.8510666143174977
```

**Update**

Based on OP's updated query:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='8/16/2021 10:00:00', end='8/16/2021 11:00:00', freq='1min'), columns=['DateTime'])

def get_rate(x):
    try:
        op = c.get_rate('CAD', 'USD', x)
    except Exception as re:
        print(re)
        op=None
    return op

df['Rate'] = df['DateTime'].apply(get_rate)
```

I have shown this only on 1 hour data. You can modify the start and end dates accordingly

Comment: Hey vivek, thanks for your answer. Just for my info, where do you have to mention the range of dates. I think i missed it in your code but i see it in the output

Comment: i also added import pandas as pd, but it says undefined name df. Im new to python, am i missing something

Comment: the dates are in the `DateTime` column in your output dataframe, that's where I picked it. df if the name of your pandas dataframe where the dates are

Comment: that is just a dummy output dataframe i created. not to be used as df for datetime. Objective is to have the code generate an ouput that looks like that in format but doesnt have to rely on a dataframe for the date range. Forget my output df for a minute. Is there a way to just get all these values from 2007 till today by minute?

Comment: Hi Vivek, for some reason I get an error. I have asked it as a new question because your code works for only some hours. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68896900/strange-currency-rates-source-not-ready-forex-python-error . Is there any way to fetch the data only for Monday to Friday between 10 am to 5 pm? lets say i want to get data from 2015 till today but only from M-F 10-5pm data