# Strange 'Currency Rates source not ready' forex_python error

Tags: python, pandas, currency, forex

I'm trying to understand forex API through python.The code that I am posting below worked for me on friday and I received all the conversion rates for the dates as desired. Strangely when I run the code today for some reason it says

> Currency Rates source not ready.

Why is this happening?

```
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
import pandas as pd
c = CurrencyRates()
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
c = CurrencyRates()


df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='8/16/2021 10:00:00', end='8/22/2021 11:00:00', freq='600min'), columns=['DateTime'])

def get_rate(x):
    try:
        op = c.get_rate('CAD', 'USD', x)
    except Exception as re:
        print(re)
        op=None
    return op

df['Rate'] = df['DateTime'].apply(get_rate)

Currency Rates Source Not Ready
Currency Rates Source Not Ready

df
Out[17]: 
              DateTime      Rate
0  2021-08-16 10:00:00  0.796374
1  2021-08-16 20:00:00  0.796374
2  2021-08-17 06:00:00  0.793031
3  2021-08-17 16:00:00  0.793031
4  2021-08-18 02:00:00  0.792469
5  2021-08-18 12:00:00  0.792469
6  2021-08-18 22:00:00  0.792469
7  2021-08-19 08:00:00  0.783967
8  2021-08-19 18:00:00  0.783967
9  2021-08-20 04:00:00  0.774504
10 2021-08-20 14:00:00  0.774504
11 2021-08-21 00:00:00       NaN
12 2021-08-21 10:00:00       NaN
13 2021-08-21 20:00:00       NaN
14 2021-08-22 06:00:00       NaN
```

How do I fix this issue? Is there a way to ignore `NaN` while making calls itself? I feel that the API only gives results for **Monday to Friday from 10 am to 5pm**. So is there a way to just get those results.

Comment: Every time I run the code it gives me the error for a different time value. Is it possible that forex has a throttle on number of API requests per second, and the requests are being made too fast occasionally?

Comment: @HenryEcker not sure about that

Comment: @HenryEcker i found that if i changed freq='600min' then i get outputs, however, for days that start having NaN values thats when i start getting the error Currency Rates Source Not Ready. I have edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [python_forex SDK](https://github.com/MicroPyramid/forex-python) uses [The Forex Api](https://theforexapi.com/documentation/), which gets its data from [The European Central Bank](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/policy_and_exchange_rates/euro_reference_exchange_rates/html/index.en.html). The European Central Bank updates the rates on a daily interval (at approximately 16:00 CET) on every working day, except on [TARGET closing days](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/services/contacts/working-hours/html/index.en.html). This means that you can only get one value for currency rates, on working days.

To get those rates you could do

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='8/16/2021 10:00:00', end='8/22/2021 11:00:00', freq='B'), columns=['DateTime'])
```

where `freq="B"` means only business days ([source](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)). When running the rest of your code this results in:

```
             DateTime      Rate
0 2021-08-16 10:00:00  0.796374
1 2021-08-17 10:00:00  0.793031
2 2021-08-18 10:00:00  0.792469
3 2021-08-19 10:00:00  0.783967
4 2021-08-20 10:00:00  0.774504
```

You could also do it for business hours with `freq="BH"`, but you would not get different rates.

Also, note that in the [python_forex SDK](https://github.com/MicroPyramid/forex-python) they say that you should use version 1.6 to avoid RatesNotAvailableError.

#### The package I have created

NB! I am not planning on maintaining it.

[Github link](https://github.com/oddaspa/easy-exchange-rates)

Install:

`pip install easy-exchange-rates`

Usage:

```py
from easy_exchange_rates import API
api = API()
time_series = api.get_exchange_rates(
  base_currency="EUR", 
  start_date="2021-01-01", 
  end_date="2021-08-13", 
  targets=["USD","CAD"]
)
data_frame = api.to_dataframe(time_series)
print(data_frame.head(5))
>>>
                 CAD       USD
2021-01-01  1.549988  1.217582
2021-01-02  1.544791  1.213500
2021-01-03  1.557791  1.223409
2021-01-04  1.566076  1.225061
2021-01-05  1.558553  1.229681
```

Comment: Hi @oddaspa. this worked the first time and failed after that not sure why

Comment: Yes, [The Forex Api](https://theforexapi.com/documentation/) is down currently. So the package is unable to retrieve data. I have a simple python package that can solve your issue though. I am not planning on maintaining it but I use a different source [Exchange.host](https://exchangerate.host/). I have updated my answer to provide the code.

Comment: @odassapa but this is showing exchange rate by day and not business hour

Comment: @NewInPython The API does only update daily, so there is no need to have it by business hour. The Forex API also only updates once per day, so there is no difference in the result. If you want to have it on an hourly basis, you can resample the data frame. This would only result in having multiple rows with the same rate value though.

Answer (score 1):

I also created a package which returns a dict with rates for a specific date for a specific base currency. Less useful for plots, but useful if you create invoices in different currencies for example. Or want to update prices for product in specific currencies.

The package used data from the European Central Bank. See https://github.com/ddofborg/exchange_rates

Example:

```py
>>> from exchange_rates import get_exchange_rates
>>> print( get_exchange_rates('USD', target_currencies=['EUR', 'CAD', 'USD'], on_date='2023-10-01') )
{'EUR': 0.9496676163342831, 'CAD': 1.3613485280151947, 'USD': 1.0}
>>> print( get_exchange_rates('EUR', target_currencies=['EUR', 'CAD', 'USD'], on_date='2023-10-01') )
{'EUR': 1.0, 'CAD': 1.4335, 'USD': 1.053}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also made an API for exchange rates (got a bit frustrated changing packages every now and then and depend on others):

[https://exchange.nanoapi.dev](https://exchange.nanoapi.dev/)

You don't need to install any 3rd party dependencies and I included examples how to use it in the above link.