# Converting different exchange rates in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

| Amount | Currency | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 45,63 | GBP | 23.02.2020 |
| 38,42 | EUR | 15.06.2019 |
| 8500 | SEK | 20.03.2021 |

I want to convert these different currencies on different time basis to GBP. I tried the following code but get an error

```
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates

c = CurrencyRates()
df['Amount'] = df.apply( lambda x: c.convert( x.Currency, 'GBP', x.Amount, x.Date), axis = 1)

*'Currency Rates source not ready'*
```

I also tried to do that on API but it is limited to 1000 datas. My record includes 95000 rows of data. Is there any possibility to convert these amount to GBP on datetime basis?

Comment: Read this post as the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68896900/strange-currency-rates-source-not-ready-forex-python-error

Comment: I have already checked this but the library has the problem I guess

Comment: *'Currency Rates source not ready'* This is the error? The only thing I can think of other than that would be the type of the variables you are passing. Try converting the type of the variable before passing it as a parameter:                       c.convert(x.Currency, 'GBP',  float(x.Amount.replace(',', '.')), datetime.strptime(x.Date, "%d.%m.%Y").date())

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation I tried it but I got the error

Comment: The error is : 'Series' object has no attribute 'Currency'. What should I do now ?

Comment: I managed to replicate the error and I believe it is in the way you are already reading your DataFrame, because you are going through the rows and not the columns of your DataFrame. Try changing the axis value.

Comment: I developed a code based on your post, when I scroll through axis 1, I can access the columns, but if I change the axis to 0, the mentioned error occurs. This will vary based on your database structure. Follow the link to the notebook https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nOFkGAiLS-ZGpEgnW-OKt7nJIMc-dglv?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for your contribution but I get the following error: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace' so the dtypes 

( Date=datetime64, Amount = 'float64', Currency = object).

Comment: So they already have the correct types, it doesn't need the type conversion that I suggested in the penultimate comment

Comment: So I don't know why it is being like this

Comment: thanks for your support so i tried  c.convert(x.Currency, 'GBP', float(str(x.Amount).replace(',', '.')), datetime.strptime(x.Date, "%d.%m.%Y").date()) that had worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made an API for exchange rates (got a bit frustrated changing packages every now and then as they stopped working):

https://exchange.nanoapi.dev

It contains data starting from 1999 from ECB. You may use it freely with no rate limits right now :)

You don't need to install any 3rd party dependencies and I included examples how to use it in the above link.

Comment: That's nice, but it hardly answers the actual question that the OP had.

Comment: @tripleee one issue the op had was the rate limiter, which is solved in my answer.